# Is it possible to get initial link/source of Firebase Dynamic Link? Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

When I receive a dynamic link in my app I process the deep link inside, also I need to log analytics with the information such as the source of the dynamic link (campaign or etc.), user_id and phone_number?

Is it possible to get an initial link, source or campaign of the dynamic link?

I know that there is a default `dynamic_link_app_open` event, however, I cannot customize it by adding `user_id` and `phone_number`.

Or are there any other options?